# CSS hover don't apply to child nodes

Tags: html, css, hover

My html setup is similar to this, the only difference is that my '.inner's are wrapped much deeper (eg. `<div><span><div class="inner">aaa</div></div></span>`)

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="inner">aaa</div>
    <div class="main anOtherClass">
        <div class="inner">aaa</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my css is:

```
.main:hover .inner {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

The problem is, that if I hover onto the first .main all of my .inners get the border. My goal is only to have the first .inner get the border. Is this even possible to do in css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors):

```
.main:hover > .inner {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

The `>` constrains this selector to `.inner` elements that are a *direct* child of `.main`,

SitePoint explains it well: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector

If you're certain you *only* want the first one (in case there are two or more adjacent ones) use `:first-child` as well:

```
.main:hover > .inner:first-child {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```